# Service php5-fpm restart doesn't work, need a new init script

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, init

When I install PHP from the default repositories `$ service php5-fpm restart` works fine.

But when I install the latest version using the well known repository `ppa:ondrej/php5`, the init script seems to be ruined. When I run `$ service php5-fpm restart` it doesn't do or say anything.

If I start the PHP daemon manually by running `$ /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` (I found this line inside /etc/init/php5-fpm.conf), it works fine.

Is there any bullet-proof install method that you are using for installing the latest PHP version with a correct init script?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried ppa:ondrej/php5, but I took a look at the deb and there is an upstart script (/etc/init/php5-fpm.conf) and an init.d script (/etc/init.d/php5-fpm). When both exist, calling `service` gives precedence to the upstart script. One difference I noticed between the scripts is that the upstart script is using the --nodaemonize flag. The following command can be used to call the init.d script:

```
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

If that works, then moving /etc/init/php5-fpm.conf out of /etc/init will cause the init.d script to have precedence.

Alternatively, fpm can be enabled when installing from source, by using the --enable-fpm option.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.install.php